# What is the proper python/django way of formatting the URL?

Tags: python, html, django

Hello fellow programmers,

I am working on a web app for cs50w course and my code is almost fully functional however, I noticed that when I use a specific function the URL not displayed properly.

Below is a function that return an entry and displays the URL properly:

```
def display_entry(request, entry):
    entrykey = util.get_entry(entry)
    markdowner = Markdown()
    context = {'entry': markdowner.convert(entrykey)}
    context.update({'title':entry})
    context.update({'content': entrykey})

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", context)
```

[image: URL displayed properly when using display_entry]

Below is a random function that returns an entry but the URL is not what it should be...

```
def random_entry(request):
    
    # retrieves a list of the entries
    entries = util.list_entries()
    entry = random.choice(entries)

    # retrives a the content of a random entry
    entrykey = util.get_entry(entry)
    
    # formats the random entry for display and returns the content to page
    markdowner = Markdown()
    context = {'entry': markdowner.convert(entrykey)}
    context.update({'title':entry})
    context.update({'content': entrykey})
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", context)
```

[image: URL not properly display when using random_entry()]

Finally, my URL patterns ...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("edit", views.edit_entry, name="edit_entry"),
    path("save", views.save_entry, name="save_entry"),
    path("search", views.search_entry, name="search_entry"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>/", views.display_entry, name="view_entry"),
    path("random_entry", views.random_entry, name="random_entry"),
]
```

I tried changing the `random_entry` to `wiki/<str:entry>/` but that created more problems.

Feel free to comment on my code without necessarily giving me the answers.

Kind regards,

A

Comment: By "_URL is not what it should be_" do you mean the url is `random_entry` when it should have been `wiki/HTML/`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to change to the correct url for the random entry, you don't want to render the page. Instead you want to *redirect* the user to the correct page by returning a response with the status code 302. You can do this quite easily by using the [`redirect` shortcut function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def random_entry(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    entry = random.choice(entries)
    return redirect('view_entry', entry=entry)
```

Comment: that was so simple yet I could not see it. Thank you for the enlightenment.